# How to avoid wrapper hell in a React project with typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was checking Twitter and I came across a post by George Moller in which he shows a way to avoid Provider Wrapper overlay using the following method

```
const buildProvidersTree = (componentsWithProps) => {
  const initialComponent = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;
  return componentsWithProps.reduce(
    (AccumulatedComponents, [Provider, props = {}]) => {
      return ({ children }) => {
        return (
          <AccumulatedComponents>
            <Provider {...props}>{children}</Provider>
          </AccumulatedComponents>
        );
      };
    },
    initialComponent
  );
};

const ProvidersTree = buildProvidersTree([
  [ThemeContext.Provider],
  [UserContext.Provider],
  [QueryClientProvider, { client: queryClient }],
  [ReduxProvider, { store }],
  [IntlProvider, { locale: usersLocale }],
]);

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <ProvidersTree>
    <App />
  </ProvidersTree>
);
```

My question is how can we do the same with typescript?

Comment: What did you try? What parts of this do you expect to be an issue with TypeScript?

Comment: Because you can compose components in React, I would say doing this provides nothing of any use and just makes the code harder for others to understand.  Also I would say having just one Provider with it's value composed into a single Object would be a way better and would be a much better way to avoid wrapper hell.

Comment: @Keith What do you mean by "having just one provider"? The example shows that there are many providers from different libraries that you all need to use.

Comment: That's a pretty inefficient implementation. Much simpler: `const buildNested = providers => ({children}) => providers.reduceRight((inner, [Provider, props]) => <Provider {...props}>{inner}</Provider>, children);`

Comment: @Bergi   And why can that not be merged into one again?, I do this plenty of times.   The rest of the code can just then do -> `const state = React.useContext(AppState)`,..  Yes, you still have to stack the providers at the start to pass this on, but because you can compose I'm still no sure what benefit flattening here gives.  `avoid wrapper hell` <--- That was the wrong terminology here if that's what you mean.  It was more the unwrapping.. :)

Comment: @Keith What do you mean by "compose" then? Merging all the provided objects in a single object, and building your own `AppStateProvider`, makes no sense, that just causes all component to re-render when anything in the app state changes. As far as I can tell, the only problem (or perceived "problem", at least - I agree it's not that bad) that is being solved here is the indentation of the code when nesting many providers.

Comment: @Bergi  Providers don't cause re-renders,  your App state would use something like Atom's, and that's what you use for re-renders.  Why do you think having an `AppStateProvider` would do this, that would be silly.

Comment: @Keith When a provider renders with a different value than before, it causes a re-render of all the components that use the provided context value. So no, a simple merging of the objects won't do. Sure, if you use a library like recoil or jotai for your app state, their provided context never changes and only provides a way to add subscriptions. But you didn't mention that, and I don't see any reason to wrap the values provided by the libraries in atoms themselves, when you can just use the hook exported by the respective library.

Comment: @Bergi  How often do props on providers change?.  And apart from that it would still happen, unless the props your changing is very close up the tree, this flattening function doesn't prevent that anyway.  So no, having your own Provider works fine,..  ps.  I'm not saying you don't use the hooks provided either, I said because of compos-ability this function is really pointless.  The `AppStateProvider` is just another option, I just find not having ****useSomething's everywhere, and having `const {client, store, myStuff} = useAppState()` is just a tad nicer.  But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Keith said in the comments. but the type-friendly version of your code is here:

```
// 3. Here we loop through the array's type and map it to make the expected array type
type ComponentsWithProps<TComponents extends readonly React.JSXElementConstructor<any>[]> = {
    [key in keyof TComponents]:
    keyof React.ComponentProps<TComponents[key]> extends never
    ? readonly [TComponents[key]]
    : readonly [TComponents[key], React.ComponentProps<TComponents[key]>]
} & { length: TComponents['length'] };

// 2. I added a generic type here to be able to get the entered argument's type
const buildProvidersTree = <T extends readonly React.JSXElementConstructor<any>[]>(componentsWithProps: ComponentsWithProps<T>) => {
    // 4. I also added this type to make the errors about `children` go away    
    const initialComponent: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>;

    return componentsWithProps.reduce(
        (AccumulatedComponents, [Provider, props = {}]) => {
            return ({ children }) => {
                return (
                    <AccumulatedComponents>
                        <Provider {...props}>{children}</Provider>
                    </AccumulatedComponents>
                );
            };
        },
        initialComponent
    );
};

const ProvidersTree = buildProvidersTree([
   [ThemeContext.Provider],
   [UserContext.Provider],
   [QueryClientProvider, { client: queryClient }],
   [ReduxProvider, { store }],
   [IntlProvider, { locale: usersLocale }],
] as const); // 1. We need to make it readonly with `as const` to tell the typescript that the array will not change and make its type a tuple
```

Answer (score -2):

Wrap each Context.Provider in a new component, defined by you, which initializes its state internally and conforms to a shared Provider interface, also defined by you, so that Typescript can reduceRight over the list of providers without needing to use the any type or other overly-complex and contrived type definitions to define the data type of each provider’s value prop, which may or may not be present, and if it is, could be the shape of any of the context’s types.

[Here's a link to my blog post, on this topic](https://pachulski.me/composing-react-providers-with-differing-value-prop-types-in-a-type-safe-way-with-typescript).

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text, View } from "react-native"

type Children = React.ReactElement | React.ReactElement[]
type Provider = ({ children }: { children: Children }) => React.ReactElement

const NameContext = React.createContext<string>("")
const AgeContext = React.createContext<number>(0)
const HeightInInchesContext = React.createContext<number>(0)

const NameProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <NameContext.Provider value={"Nick"}>{children}</NameContext.Provider>
)

const AgeProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <AgeContext.Provider value={32}>{children}</AgeContext.Provider>
)

const HeightInInchesProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <HeightInInchesContext.Provider value={72}>
    {children}
  </HeightInInchesContext.Provider>
)

const ComposedProviders = ({
  providers,
  children,
}: {
  providers: Provider[]
  children: React.ReactElement
}): React.ReactElement =>
  providers.reduceRight((acc, Provider) => <Provider>{acc}</Provider>, children)

const App = (): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <ComposedProviders
      providers={[NameProvider, AgeProvider, HeightInInchesProvider]}
    >
      <PersonalDetails />
    </ComposedProviders>
  )
}

const PersonalDetails = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const name = React.useContext(NameContext)
  const age = React.useContext(AgeContext)
  const heightInInches = React.useContext(HeightInInchesContext)
  return (
    <View style=>
      <Text>Name: {name}</Text>
      <Text>Age: {age}</Text>
      <Text>
        Height: {heightInInches}
        {'"'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Please [do not just post some links to elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), but rather a self-contained answer to the question.