# Composing React Providers with Value props in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, functional-programming, composition

I'd like to avoid [this "problem"](https://x.com/swyx/status/1644124125148110849?s=20) of nesting dozens of providers around my app component, resulting in a sideways-mountain-looking hierarchy of provider components. I'd like use composition to compose those providers. My providers usually have values. I've found a way to compose them using javascript (without typescript) - or by using Typescript with the use of the `any` type - But I'd really love to find a way to compose Providers that may or may not have values in Typescript without the using the `any` type. I *think* all that's holding me back is my depth of understanding of Typescript. Here is the simplest example that I can easily contrive of a provider-composing-component written in Typescript that is trying to compose two providers which both have values (I'd like to also compose providers without values in a type-safe way, but I think the TS error I get here illustrates the root of the problem I've been struggling with):

```js
import React from "react"
import RefreshablePlayersContext from "contexts/RefreshablePlayersContext"
import RefreshableGamesContext from "contexts/RefreshableGamesContext"
import type { RefreshablePlayersContext as RefreshablePlayersContextType } from "types/RefreshablePlayersContext"
import type { RefreshableGamesContext as RefreshableGamesContextType } from "types/RefreshableGamesContext"
import type { Player } from "types/Player"
import type { Game } from "types/Game"
import type { RefreshableRequest } from "types/RefreshableRequest"

interface ProviderWithValue<ContextType> {
  provider: React.Provider<ContextType>
  value: ContextType
}

interface ProvidersProps {
  children: React.ReactElement
}

const Providers = ({ children }: ProvidersProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const [refreshableGames, setRefreshableGames] = React.useState<
    RefreshableRequest<Game[]>
  >({
    status: "Not Started",
  })

  const [refreshablePlayers, setRefreshablePlayers] = React.useState<
    RefreshableRequest<Player[]>
  >({
    status: "Not Started",
  })

  const providersWithValues: [
    ProviderWithValue<RefreshableGamesContextType>,
    ProviderWithValue<RefreshablePlayersContextType>,
  ] = [
    {
      provider: RefreshableGamesContext.Provider,
      value: { refreshableGames, setRefreshableGames },
    },
    {
      provider: RefreshablePlayersContext.Provider,
      value: { refreshablePlayers, setRefreshablePlayers },
    },
  ]

  return providersWithValues.reduceRight((acc, CurrentProviderWithValue) => {
    return (
      // the Typescript error is on the following line; complaining about the
      // value which is passed to the `value` prop below:
      <CurrentProviderWithValue.provider value={CurrentProviderWithValue.value}>
        {acc}
      </CurrentProviderWithValue.provider>
    )
  }, children)
}

export default Providers
```

The Typescript error, for the line called out in the comments above, reads:

> Type 'RefreshableGamesContext | RefreshablePlayersContext' is not assignable to type 'RefreshableGamesContext & RefreshablePlayersContext'.
> Type 'RefreshableGamesContext' is not assignable to type 'RefreshableGamesContext & RefreshablePlayersContext'.
> Type 'RefreshableGamesContext' is missing the following properties from type 'RefreshablePlayersContext': refreshablePlayers, setRefreshablePlayers

I've not seen Typescript's `&` operator before, but after looking it up, it looks like it's expecting the `value` of both of the `ProviderAndValue<T>` values to both have the attributes that each of them have; e.g. the *intersection* of the two possible values.

I don't understand why that is, given that I explicitly type each index of the `ProviderWithValues` array, when I type it:

```js
const providersWithValues: [
    ProviderWithValue<RefreshableGamesContextType>,
    ProviderWithValue<RefreshablePlayersContextType>,
  ] = [
    {
      provider: RefreshableGamesContext.Provider,
      value: { refreshableGames, setRefreshableGames },
    },
    {
      provider: RefreshablePlayersContext.Provider,
      value: { refreshablePlayers, setRefreshablePlayers },
    },
  ]
```

Is there a way to keep Typescript's type safety (without using the `any` type) to compose these two providers, which accept values of different types?

(Bonus points if your solution also provisions for composing Providers - which do not have a value prop - in a type-safe way!)

Comment: Just use a state manager instead. Context is going to cause your whole app to re-render every time a value changes. It's not meant for volatile state

Comment: @Abe It'll only re-render those parts that actually use the respective context. And no, not all context is about state.

Comment: Have a look at [How to avoid wrapper hell in a React project with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77151720/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi! The solution there looks interesting (and I did look around _a lot_ for related SO questions and never found that one - so thank you!), but it also uses the `any` type, which I'd like to avoid, if possible. Maybe it's not possible. But I feel that if I'm making the tree-builder non-generic (e.g. not copy-and-paste reusable for other applications), in a context (pun intended) where TS knows the types of what I'm trying to compose, then I should be able to get a non-`any`-using, type-safe implementation working. Maybe that SO post is the best solution around?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap each Context.Provider in a new component, defined by you, which initializes its state internally and conforms to a shared Provider interface, also defined by you, so that Typescript can reduceRight over the list of providers without needing to use the any type or other overly-complex and contrived type definitions to define the data type of each provider’s value prop, which may or may not be present, and if it is, could be the shape of any of the context’s types.

[Here's a link to my blog post, on this topic](https://pachulski.me/composing-react-providers-with-differing-value-prop-types-in-a-type-safe-way-with-typescript).

```js
import React from "react"
import { Text, View } from "react-native"

type Children = React.ReactElement | React.ReactElement[]
type Provider = ({ children }: { children: Children }) => React.ReactElement

const NameContext = React.createContext<string>("")
const AgeContext = React.createContext<number>(0)
const HeightInInchesContext = React.createContext<number>(0)

const NameProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <NameContext.Provider value={"Nick"}>{children}</NameContext.Provider>
)

const AgeProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <AgeContext.Provider value={32}>{children}</AgeContext.Provider>
)

const HeightInInchesProvider: Provider = ({ children }) => (
  <HeightInInchesContext.Provider value={72}>
    {children}
  </HeightInInchesContext.Provider>
)

const ComposedProviders = ({
  providers,
  children,
}: {
  providers: Provider[]
  children: React.ReactElement
}): React.ReactElement =>
  providers.reduceRight((acc, Provider) => <Provider>{acc}</Provider>, children)

const App = (): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <ComposedProviders
      providers={[NameProvider, AgeProvider, HeightInInchesProvider]}
    >
      <PersonalDetails />
    </ComposedProviders>
  )
}

const PersonalDetails = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const name = React.useContext(NameContext)
  const age = React.useContext(AgeContext)
  const heightInInches = React.useContext(HeightInInchesContext)
  return (
    <View style=>
      <Text>Name: {name}</Text>
      <Text>Age: {age}</Text>
      <Text>
        Height: {heightInInches}
        {'"'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Please [do not just post some links to elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), but rather a self-contained answer to the question. And don't post the same answer to multiple questions!

Comment: sorry but it looks like you just added more complexity to ultimately create the same underlying react tree. In the process you sacrificed ability to pass additional props to each context, as required.

Comment: So the complexity argument isn't wrong. Making the tree composable by wrapping every provider adds some boiler plate and reducing the tree back together adds some mental overhead. Agreed. I'm not sure what you mean when you say the ability to pass additional props to each context was sacrificed, though. If you want to pass more data to, for example, the `NameContext.Provider`, you could still change the contexts type to, say `{ first_name: string; last_name: string }` and then create states for those values and pass them in from within the provider. Did I miss your point?

Comment: @pachun I mean how would you represent `<NameProvider myprop={myvalue} .../>` using your `providers={[ NameProvider,... ]}`?

Comment: @Mulan That's actually happening in the example that I posted. The Provider that you get when you do `<AnyContext.Provider value={...}/>` takes one prop that we care about (AFAIK); `value`. In the example above, we wrap `<NameContext.Provider value={...} />` in our own `<NameProvider />`; within that `<NameProvider />` we initialize all state that we need to pass to the value prop of `<NameContext.Provider value={...} />`. In the example, the value is hardcoded to `Nick`, but it could be a value from `useState` instead. Or several. Does that make sense? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @pachun Yes, I mean `NameProvider` only has a `children` prop, so how would you pass additional props _at composition time_?  It's common for providers to take props, such as `<Provider store={store} ... />` or `<StyleProvider renderer={renderer} .../>`, see the ["problem"](https://x.com/swyx/status/1644124125148110849?s=20) you linked. These values cannot be hard-coded in pre-defined providers. Using your strategy, how do you suggest fixing the "problem"? `<ComposedProviders  providers={[ Provider, StyleProvider, ... ]} .../>`, but where to specify `store` and `renderer` props?

Comment: Any props that `NameContext.Provider` accepts can be imported or initialized from within `NameProvider`, which wraps `NameContext.Provider`, and passes it its state in the same way your `App` component had been passing them to `NameContext.Provider`, originally. If `NameContext.Provider` also accepted those `store` and `renderer` props, you can initialize or import them in `NameProvider` the same way you had been initializing or importing them in your `App` component. Or if not - why can't you? I don't understand how you could import or initialize something in one component and not in another.

Comment: @pachun consider a simple example of `function MyComponent(props) { return <ProviderA a={props.a}><ProviderB b={props.b} /></ProviderA> }` How would you rewrite that using `ComposedProviders`?  What I'm saying is you can't pre-define `ProviderA` and `ProviderB` because the `a` and `b` props are not known until the contexts are being composed.

Comment: Ah, I see. So in defense of your point, I hadn't considered initializing a context with prop values. However, that prop value is being passed down into your component. Could you possibly initialize that prop value in a context in the root of your app? That'd allow you to still use this approach and avoid prop drilling. In defense of my approach, I think most people have this issue at their topmost level component. I've personally never initialized a Provider, let alone a set of them which I want to compose, anywhere lower than the topmost App component of the component tree.

Comment: Actually, I have initialized providers at a lower level. I don't think I've felt a desire to compose multiple ones at any level other than my topmost App level component. We have had `FormContext.Provider`'s for forms, but it's just one provider, so I hadn't felt a need to compose there. That said, there might be a way to get what you're getting as a prop in your provider-instantiating-component in some other way - possibly with another `<App />`-level context.